# Перестановка слов в ФИО в ячейках

Tags: excel, перестановка

Как поставить фамилию после имени и отчества в ячейках Экселя? Например, изначально ФИО стоит так: "Собачкин Андрей Олегович". Мне надо получить "Андрей Олегович Собачкин". Нужна формула, а не макрос.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что Вы хотите, чтобы Эксель как то сам в правильном порядке поставил фамилию, имя и отчество, независимо от того, в каком порядке это напечатал пользователь? Тогда я советую добавить тег Эксель - если тут есть такой... а то люди далекие от "офиса" могут просто не въехать, про какие такие ячейки идёт речь. И, кстати, я сомневаюсь, что есть такая формула, и даже такой макрос...

Comment: S.H., да, в экселе. Порядок важен. Пользователь уже расписал ФИО в порядке "фамилия, имя, отчество". А мне нужно, что было так: "имя отчество фамилия". Для этого мне нужна формула, а то у меня аж 150 таких ФИО в экселе

Answer (score 1):

На выбор. Ищем первый пробел и по нему делим текст:

```
=ПСТР(A2&" "&A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)+1;ДЛСТР(A2))
=ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)+1;30)&" "&ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)-1)
=ЗАМЕНИТЬ(A2;1;ПОИСК(" ";A2);)&" "&ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)-1)
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2));)&" "&ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)-1)
```

---

Функция пользователя (`UDF`), позволяющая расставлять три слова в любом порядке или возвращать повторы слов.

```
Function fShiftName(sName As String, Optional j1 As Long = 2, _
                    Optional j2 As Long = 3, Optional j3 As Long = 1) As String
    Dim aSpl
    
    aSpl = Split(sName, " ")
    fShiftName = aSpl(j1 - 1) & " " & aSpl(j2 - 1) & " " & aSpl(j3 - 1)
End Function
```

Параметры, передаваемые в функцию: ссылка на ячейку (или текст) и три числа, устанавливающие порядок слов. Ссылка обязательна, числа - опционально (по умолчанию слова переставляются в порядке 2, 3, 1 (второе, третье, первое). Порядок по умолчанию можно поменять, изменив значения переменных `jx`

Функция записывается в общий модуль  в редакторе `VBA`. В ячейке вызывать функцию формулой.

Примеры для исходного текста `Первый Второй Третий`

`=fShiftName(A2)` - с параметрами по умолчанию: `Второй Третий Первый`

`=fShiftName(A2;;;1)` - то же, что и по умолчанию: `Второй Третий Первый`

`=fShiftName("Первый Второй Третий";3;1;2)` - другая перестановка: `Третий Первый Второй`

`=fShiftName("Первый Второй Третий";3;;3)` - повтор слова: `Третий Третий Третий`

`=fShiftName(A2;3;3;1)` - повтор с перестановкой: `Третий Третий Первый`

Answer (score 0):

Задача эквивалентна задаче переставить первое слово в конец строки.

Подразумевая, что исходный текст в ячейке `D5`и слова разделены пробелом:

- Если в Excel'е есть поддержка регулярных выражений, как в libreoffice, то можно обойтись этим:

  ```
  REGEX(D5;"^(\S*)\s(.*)$";"$2 $1")
  ```
- Если нет, то придётся шаманить что-то такое:

  ```
  CONCAT(RIGHT(D5;LEN(D5)-FIND(" ";D5));" ";LEFT(D5;FIND(" ";D5)-1))
  ```

  или в русской версии:

  ```
  СЦЕПИТЬ(ПРАВСИМВ(D5;ДЛСТР(D5)-НАЙТИ(" ";D5));" ";ПРАВСИМВ(D5;НАЙТИ(" ";D5)-1))
  ```

Comment: спасибо, но не выходит. Эксель выдает ошибку #ИМЯ?

Comment: В `Excel` регулярки функциями листа не поддерживаются. Во второй формуле в локальной версии нужно применять локализованные функции: *СЦЕПИТЬ, ПРАВСИМВ, ДЛСТР, ПОИСК, ЛЕВСИМВ*.

Comment: @vikttur, спасибо.... не ожидал, что в документе нельзя смешивать формулы разных локализаций...

Comment: @vikttur, сделал...

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете MS Excel 2013 или новее, то можете решить эту задачу без формул с помощью инструмента [**Мгновенное заполнение**](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-excel-3f9bcf1e-db93-4890-94a0-1578341f73f7) (по ссылке найдёте короткое обучающее видео и подробные инструкции)